# Как вывести название процессора с помощью Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Мне нужно чтобы код смог вернуть строку с названием ЦП. Внимание, не

> AMD64 Family 23 Model 1 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD

А вот так

> AMD Ryzen5 1600 8 CPU 3.20GHz

Или нечто подобное. Помогите как сможете! Оп. сис. - Windows 10

Comment: Обращаться к WMI

Comment: Ещё можно найти в реестре в ветке HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\

Answer (score 2):

```
import platform
print(platform.processor())
```

Или таким образом:

```
import cpuinfo
cpuinfo.cpu.info[0]['model name']
```

Выдаёт str такого формата: 'Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.60GHz'

Answer (score 1):

Получение из реестра:

```
from winreg import *

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0")
name = QueryValueEx(aKey, 'ProcessorNameString')[0]
print(name)
```